# How to properly extract files (out of memory)?

Tags: android

At start up of my app I want to extract my images (if they does not exists) from drawable folder to internal app folder to use later with FileProvider. Images have dimensions 2000*2000 and average size 380kb, format png.
Those images are not to be displayed (smaller ones are used to display). They are only for file sharing and I have to keep their original size.
I get out of memory at calling

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResID);
```

Code

```
private void extractImages() {
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.smile_list_share);
    File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
    File checkImage;
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
      int imageResID = imgs.getResourceId(i, 0);
      if (imageResID > 0) {
        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageResID);
        checkImage = new File(imagePath, name + ".png");

        if (!checkImage.exists()) {
          Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResID);
          boolean b = saveBitmapToFile(imagePath, name + ".png", bm, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);

          Log.e("mcheck","saved "+b+", file "+name);
          Log.e("mcheck", "file does not exists " + name);
        } else {
          Log.e("mcheck", "file exists " + name);
        }
      } else {
        Log.e("mcheck", "ERROR " + i);
      }
    }
    imgs.recycle();
  }

  public boolean saveBitmapToFile(File dir, String fileName, Bitmap bm,
      Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {

    File imageFile = new File(dir, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
      fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

      bm.compress(format, quality, fos);
      bm.recycle();
      fos.close();

      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("app", e.getMessage());
      if (fos != null) {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I dont need to create bitmap object at all. It is possible to obtaine intput stream from getResourses directly.

```
public boolean saveBitmapToFile(File dir, String fileName, int imageResourse) {

    File imageFile = new File(dir, fileName);

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
      fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(imageResourse);
      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
      }
      inputStream.close();
      fos.close();

      return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("app", e.getMessage());
      if (fos != null) {
        try {
          fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
          inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call recycle on your bitmap object everytime you are done with it.
Here is a good guide on how to manipulate bitmaps efficiently 
https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: bitmap is recycled in savebitmapToFile method, but out of memmory strikes before this method is called. Also thos images are not supposed to be displayed, they are required for file sharing,thus i have to preserve their original dimensions.

Comment: oh my bad I didn't see your saveBitmapToFile() method. Where is your crash happening exactly ? this line ? Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResID);

Comment: yes, to check it i comented everything else and put bm.recycle strait after it and got Out of memmory